# Bind iron-page and and

Tags: javascript, typescript, polymer

I just began to learn the Polymer and at the moment to bind the paper-tabs and iron-pages together, so if I click the tab the content will be loaded dynamically. After reading the documentation here is what I have at the moment

```
<app-toolbar>
<paper-tabs class="tabs" attr-for-selected="page" selected="{{ selectedBrowsePage }}">
    <paper-tab page="artists">
      Artist
    </paper-tab >
    <paper-tab page="artists">
      Album
    </paper-tab>
    <paper-tab page="artists">
      Project
    </paper-tab>
  </paper-tabs>
</app-toolbar>
```

```
  <iron-pages selectedBrowsePage="artist" selected="{{ selectedBrowsePage }}">
    <div attr-for-selected="page" >1</div>
  </iron-pages>
```

But it still doesn't work...could you please give me a hint how could I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `iron-pages` block has to be fixed - it consumes the `selectedBrowsePage` via binding but does not propagate the change anywhere. The `selectedBrowsePage="artist"` bit is wrong too, no such property exists on `iron-pages` element. Also it is invalid to use `camelCase` for properties to be set up through markup, use `dash-case` if you need.

It should be something along:

```
<iron-pages attr-for-selected="page" selected="{{ selectedBrowsePage }}">
  <div page="artist">1</div>
  <div page="etc...">2</div>
  ...
</iron-pages>
```

Pretty much the same as in `paper-tabs`. This way the `iron-pages` element once it receives some value (like "artist") through `selected="{{selectedBrowsePage}}"` it will look for any child element that has the attribute specified by `attr-for-selected` set to the corresponding value (here the first `div`) and do its magical switching.

Once you get a hang of how it's working you could drop the `attr-for-selected` altogether as the default behavior is to use indexes.

Look throught [PSK](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/polymer-starter-kit/), it has that pattern laid out pretty straight.